# Is the following assert syntax correct?

Tags: java, assert, assertions

I have the following assert statement;

```
assertTrue(xyz.getTotalRecords() == 50);
```

I am getting an error

```
java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:92)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:43)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:54)
```

Am I doing something wrong OR is it an issue with what is actually being asserted ?

Answer (score 2):

You get an assertion error because `xyz.getTotalRecords()` is not `50` but your assertion is otherwise correct, although you might want to use `assertEquals` instead

Answer (score 1):

Good style is using `assertEquals(xyz.getTotalRecords(), 50)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since it compiled, the syntax is correct. You get this exception because the condition is not `true`.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I doing something wrong OR is it an issue with what is actually
>   being asserted ?

The syntax is fine. The problem is with assertion. Your expected value is not same as actual one.

Try providing a message for when assertion fails: [JUnit](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertTrue%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29)

```
assertTrue("Expected size: 50, Actual size: " + xyz.getTotalRecords(), xyz.getTotalRecords() == 50);
```

or `assertEquals("Expected size: 50, Actual size: " + xyz.getTotalRecords(), xyz.getTotalRecords(), 50);`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing all right. You just get failed assertion. BTW, good practice is to use [Hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/) that way:

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
...
assertThat(xyz.getTotalRecords(), is(50));
```